# Drupal search - 2 search pages using their own settings

Tags: search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drupal search - 2 search pages using their own settings](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58688/drupal-search-2-search-pages-using-their-own-settings)

I would like to have 2 pages: - http://domain.com/search-1 - http://domain.com/search-2

Where search-1 is limited to results of contenttype blog and search-2 is limited to results of contenttype news.

I've been looking for contrib modules but cannot find anything. Please help me out, thanks.

Cheers, Wietse