# Drupal search - 2 search pages using their own settings

Tags: search

I would like to have 2 pages:
- http://domain.com/search-1
- http://domain.com/search-2

Where search-1 is limited to results of contenttype blog and search-2 is limited to results of contenttype news.

I've been looking for contrib modules but cannot find anything.
Please help me out, thanks.

Cheers,
Wietse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would consider to use Views along with exposed filters to create your special "search" pages. E.g. create a view which only lists blog entries and then add a filter for body text to it.

My next approach would be the [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) module along with the [Search API Page module](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_page).

Last but not least, you always can write a module for that. ;) I would take a look at different search modules which already implement additional search pages.

Comment: Thanks Paul, the search API page module will help me out.